# accessing a number from a file in bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have a file abc.out. This file only has a number written in it.
I want to access this file, store this number in a variable and use an if condition to check some condition.
How do I do this in my bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file contents into a variable with:

```
var=$(< filename)
```

or:

```
read var < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the followign syntax.

```
NUM=$(cat abc.out)
```

or

```
NUM=`cat abc.out`
```